# Magento 2: Grouped Products - Change QTY field to dropdown

Tags: php, dropdown, magento2, product-quantity

I have created a grouped product in Magento CE2.4.2. Instead of having a text input field for each option I would like to work with dropdowns.

This is the original Magento code:

```
<input type="number"
name="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
data-selector="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getQty() * 1) ?>"
title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
class="input-text qty"
data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
```

I have changed this to:

```
<select name="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]"
data-selector="super_group[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>]" 
class="qty-select" id="qty" type="number" 
data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}" 
data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box" />
<option selected value="0">0</option>           
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. When trying to add any option in any quantity to cart I get the following error message:

```
Please specify the quantity of product(s).
```

I also tried to remove the "0" option for testing reasons, but this did not change anything.

Could anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now realized my mistake. I removed the JS validation part from the select element:

```
data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}" 
data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box" />
```

After removing this it works fine. So I will just pass on the inline validation at this point in time.